# MySQL join causing duplicate results

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a query out of two tables.  This should be straightforward; however, my results duplicate.  I can not use DISTINCT or GROUP BY since there is not a unique ID.  For testing, my primary table has 87 rows. With no WHERE identified I get 174 results. My two tables are as follows:

table - lifegroups_attendance (date is a date field, time is a varchar)
No unique ID - a combo of date/time/group would be closest to it

```
date | time | group| attendance
--------------------------------
1/3/15 | 6:30 PM | Adults | 125
1/3/15 | 11:00 AM | Adults | 621
1/4/15 | Saturday | Kids | 289
1/4/15 | Sun PM | Adults | 621
```

table - sat_week_date_map (the start of the week is Saturday instead of MySQL built in Sun or Mon option)
 Date is the primary ID

```
date | week
---------------
1/3/15 | 1
1/4/15 | 1
1/5/15 | 1
1/10/15 | 2
```

I need to get a result that looks like this:

```
week | group | attendance
1    |    adults |   125 
1    |    adults |   621
1    |    adults |   621 (This is not a duplicate - date/time is different)
2    |    adults |   475 
2    |    adults |   276
2    |    kids   |   289
```

Instead I'm getting

```
week | group | attendance
1    |    adults |   125 
1    |    adults |   621
1    |    adults |   621 (This is not a duplicate - date/time is different)
2    |    adults |   475 
2    |    adults |   276
2    |    kids   |   289
1    |    adults |   125  (repeats every record over again)
1    |    adults |   621
1    |    adults |   621 (This is not a duplicate - date/time is different)
2    |    adults |   475 
2    |    adults |   276
2    |    kids   |   289
```

The query I'm currently using is:

```
SELECT   wd.week, la.group AS group, la.attendance
FROM     sat_week_date_map  AS wd JOIN lifegroups_attendance AS la 
ON    la.date =  wd.date;
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your query returns `week, date, attendandance`, why does your sample result have `week, group, attendance`?

Comment: I don't see where the attendance numbers in your result come from. Ther's no `125` or `621` in the input.

Comment: You say the second `1 adults 621` is not a duplicate because the time is different. But shouldn't the attendance column be different at the different times, like in your `lifegroups_attendance` table?

Comment: I've adjusted the query.  I've had multiple iterations and removed date at one point and added group just to see what happens.  It should be querying week, group, attendance.  The data is sample data... the numbers are not accurate. I just threw some in to show the results I'm trying to get. I've edited the original data to now use the same numbers.  The attendance numbers in my real number have quite a few duplicates at different times.  Yes, it's odd but apparently different service times have the same attendance numbers by chance.  Does that help to see what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can warp your query with another query and then use distinct like:

```
SELECT distinct * 
FROM (SELECT   wd.week, la.group AS group, la.attendance
FROM     sat_week_date_map  AS wd JOIN lifegroups_attendance AS la 
ON    la.date =  wd.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check carefully if you have multiple entries for the same date in sat_week_date_map. If there are multiple such entries, they will result in apparently duplicated results.

```
SELECT date, COUNT(*) FROM sat_week_date_map GROUP BY date HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```